# Python how to automate define a function for pivot table and for loop

Tags: python, function, for-loop, pivot

I made a random table and I want to transfer it to pivot tables, using define a function and also for loop. And I want to make the code reusable and automatically.

[Original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g249.png)

[pivot table I would like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYNGu.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have the data loaded into a list or perhaps a pandas dataframe or sql table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why a FOR loop is required to do such operation, I've defined a very simple function which will generate the required output.

```
def pivoting(x):
    new_df = x.pivot(index = ["Date","State"], columns = ["Name"], values = ["Height", "Weight", "Grade"]).fillna(0)
    new_df.columns = [c[0] + " " + c[1] for c in new_df.columns]
    return new_df
pivoting(df)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I would like to have Alice Height, Bob Height, Alice Weight, Bob Weight, and more like a one level pivot table. And I'm trying to add this line after but not sure how. ['_'.join(str(s).strip() for s in col if s) for col in df.columns]

Comment: Modified the code to give you one-level headers. if this is what you are looking, mark my post as correct answer. thanks

Comment: If I want to add this pivoting function into class as a method, what should I do with x?

Answer (score 0):

Read the file in pandas. See the documentation on [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Then,

```
df = pd.set_index(['Date', 'State', 'Name').unstack()
df
```

Then you can write `df` to to another excel or csv file.

Comment: Thank you, but it would be a two level pivot table, I just need one.

Comment: @Jonnie - your pic is a 2 level pivot of Date and State. If you want just 1, play with the `set_index` array, `unstack` and `reset_index`. YouTube is your friend!